# What's the bracha on mozzarella sticks?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mezonot-beracha, shehakol-beracha

Do the breadcrumbs on mozzarella sticks require that you wash or at least say mezonot or do we say that it's only used as a cooking agent and therefore you would make a shehakol on the cheese?

Is there a difference if the sticks are fried or baked?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a famous discussion of ikar (principal) and tafel (accessory). Normally the bracha is on the ikar but mezonot is important enough that in some cases it might justify a mezonot bracha even if it is only the tafel. See for instance [here](http://www.aish.com/jl/jewish-law/blessings/20-Primary-and-Secondary-Foods.html) and [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/04/05/q-a-guide-to-the-halachos-of-brachos-ikar-tafel/) for more background.

**In the case of mozzarela sticks**, if the crumbs are highly meaningful, and you eat the sticks for the crumbs, there might be a discussion of whether mezonot is justified. But if they are only to give an interesting crunch, then it is clearly sheakol. One of the meaningful differentiating element is the thickness of the coating - thin is very clearly sheakol - thick might lead to more question of mezonot.

**The question is asked for schnitzels** (breaded meat, where the crumbs are much more significant and part of the nature of the dish), and unless the bread covering is really thick, or you eat the shnitzel just for the crumbs, then the brakha is sheakol. See for instance [here](http://shaareihoraah.org/wordpress/?p=620) or Yalkut Yosef (Brachot, vol 3, pg 426).

**So kal vakhomer for cheese sticks, there would be little justification for mezonot.**

Closest direct analogy I could find is fish sticks being sheakol. See [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/Brachot.html) and [here](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/#meat)

PS. Note that for schnitzels, a number of poskim agree that the correct theoretical bracha is mezonot, and suggest to pick a piece of breadcrumbs to say mezonot, but in practice most poskim agree the bracha le-maasse is sheakol. See references above.

PPS. No difference between baked or fried in this case - although it does make a difference for bread products, e.g., there is a long discussion by poskim re sufganiot/doughnuts on hanuka, since the dough is hala dough and it is only the oil and custom that justifies the usual mezonot on them.

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim about schnitzel and/or your _kal v'chomer_ to cheese sticks?

Comment: Working on them :-> but just reviewed this a few weeks ago

Comment: @MichaelBloch, I remember reading somewhere that shnitzel is mezonot for sefardim.

Comment: The Kal VaHomer to me is surprising. I don't see why it's not a parallel case.

Comment: @Ani Yodea no the machloket is much stronger for ashkenazim, R Elyashiv said mezonot, R Feinstein, R Yaacov Kamenetsky and others sheakol. R Yitzhak Yosef (Yalkut Yosef, Brachot vol 3 pg 426) the Chief **Sephardic** Rabbi of Israel says sheakol

Comment: @MichaelBloch, why is washing never mentioned by the poskim? Ah! The breadcrumbs less than the size of a kezayis are never hamotzie!

Comment: @Ani Yodea there are cases of needing to wash before eating mezonot, e.g., if the quantity is significant and kvia seuda (forms a full meal), e.g., eating two slices of mezonot pizza - but then you also need hamotzi and birkat hamazon

Comment: I get what you say about schnitzel. However, chicken nuggets, today (most frozen ones sold in U.S.) seem to have far more coating than chicken, per piece. My thinking is that this should be mezonot. Have you located any article that confirms or refutes this? Related, nowadays, the frozen gefilte fish loaves have more matazh meal than fish (except for the *Pesachdicke* ones). Maybe this warrants *mezonot* or, perhaps, washing & *hamotzi*?

Comment: @DanF as soon as there is more coating than chicken, or as soon as you eat it for the coating (like an ice-cream that you would eat for the cone) then you need to say mezonot indeed. See for instance [here](http://dinonline.org/2011/04/05/q-a-guide-to-the-halachos-of-brachos-ikar-tafel/) under "Schnitzel" where he says _if the coating around the schnitzel is thick, many Poskim are of the opinion that the beracha will be only mezonos, since the mezonos is to also give its own taste_

Comment: @MichaelBloch Thanks. I'll need to view the linked article, later.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://culinarykosher.com/recipe/527#.VngYl_krIdA) site lists shehakol but doesn't list a reason. I assume that the cheese is considered the ikkar.